# Count the number in a big range whose digital sum is multiple of 49

Tags: algorithm, dynamic

Assume the range is `int('1234567890' * 100)`.

i want count how many numbers whose digital sum is multiple of 49. the result modulo 1000000007.

For Example :

Digital sum of `499999` is `49`, it's a multiple of `49`, so in range from 1 to 499999, the answer is `1`.

I've discovered that the digital sum seems to be periodic.

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

But I don't know if it's related to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: for a given upper bound with digits, `d_1 d_2 ... d_n` think about how many partitions are there of `49` with less than `n` parts. Then ask a similar question, incrementing `d_1` step by step from 0 to its original value. When it reaches its original value, set `d_2` to zero and repeat the procedure.

```
0 [...d_n] -> how many partitions of 49 with less than n parts?
1 [...d_n] -> how many partitions of 49 - 1 with less than n parts?
...
d_1, 0 [...d_n] -> how many partitions of 49 - d_1 with less than n-1 parts?
d_1, 1 [...d_n] -> how many partitions of 49 - d_1 - 1 with less than n-1 parts?
...
d_1, d_2, 0 [...d_n] -> num partitions of 49 - d_1 - d_2 with less than n-2 parts?
etc.
```

Comment: Thanks, i will give it a try.

Comment: @KIDJourney thanks for accepting the answer. Looking at this now; another, possibly more efficient method could be a straightforward [digit DP](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/digit-dp-introduction). I would also look into the possibility of optimising further based on modular arithmetic with prime powers.